# Meaning of "to sway prices"

Tags: meaning

What is the precise meaning of "sway" when used as in the below examples? I don't understand the kind of influence that is implied. I have gone through its various definitions and I am not sure which one it can be. Does it mean:

- to control prices
- to fully control prices
- to cause prices to swing back and forth
- merely to have an effect on prices
- something else?

> The oil industry tries to **sway prices**

> He now controls 25% of global production, which enables him to **sway prices**

> The SEC filed a lawsuit, saying the trader tried to **sway prices**

> Russia **sways oil prices** very effectively

> Trading by pension funds does not **sway prices**

> Meme investors are a powerful force that can **sway stock prices**

Comment: It  implies — control/influence, example :- Russia sways(controls) oil prices very effectively.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but, to me, "to control" and "to influence" have different meanings. "To control" implies the ability to fully determine the course of prices, so it's a very strong effect, whereas "to influence" may imply to affect prices a bit, which is a much lighter effect.

Comment: (For me)Here, control means:-limits the price. So, you can say Russia very effectively control the oil price so that it's less than a particular amount.Influence means:-to change or affect the way the price develop. (It may indirectness), it's depends the context, you can use it by your need.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sway  from Old Norse sveigja (“to bend, bow”). To simplify maters you can take "sway" to mean one of two things 1. "to affect a change or changes in something(usually for self-benefit)", 2. "To cause back and forth motion in something"

Answer (score 1):

In this context, it means *to influence in a particular direction*. This would be a direction that was desired by the influencer for whatever reason, most likely for personal gain or due to a personal preference.

A good way to spot the difference between 'sway' used to mean *to influence* or *to cause something to move back and forth* is if the verb is being used transitively, or intransitively. When used with a direct object, it usually means *to influence*.

- He **swayed the decision**.
- He caused the ladder **to sway**.

This is because, with the alternative definition, 'swaying' isn't an action carried out by a person *on* an object; it is the resulting action of the object caused by something else. For example, you might *rock* or *shake* an object, and then the object in turn would *sway*.

Comment: Thanks. What is meant by "to influence" in this particular case? Is it to fully control the outcome of something, or is it the more mild version of having an effect on the outcome?

Comment: @goalie To influence isn't necessarily the same as to control... control suggests you determine the outcome, whereas influence is something less direct, although an influence can be described as 'strong' to denote just how far it goes to achieve an outcome.